# Setting up MySQL (Master-Slave) replication with all ready configured databases/tables

Tags: mysql, replication, configuration

I am trying to configure MySQL databases using the Master-Slave Replication. Before I realized that I had to set up my environment using this replication, I already have 2 separate servers running their own MySQL DB. Each of these servers are configured the exact same. The MySQL DB are configured with hundreds of tables.

Is there a way that i can set up (Master-Slave) Replication using the configured DB's? Or will i have to start from scratch and configure the Replication first and then load in all the DB tables

For the example below, could I replace 'slave' and 'password' with the current username and password I have already configured?

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Same with the commands below:

```
mysql&gt; CHANGE MASTER TO
-&gt; MASTER_HOST='X.X.X.X',
-&gt; MASTER_USER='slave',
-&gt; MASTER_PASSWORD='password',
-&gt; MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
-&gt; MASTER_LOG_POS=327;
```

Comment: Are the datasets the same on both machines? You state they are identically configured. What is the role of each machine? Are they both being used by applications that are making changes to the data? Depending on your intention it's viable that you can configure replication without having to remove the data and starting a new import.

Comment: The datasets are the same on both machines. Before I knew they had to be configured a certain way, i just configured them the same. One of these machines should host the db and the other one should just point to that db (in the end, using only one db). If that makes sense..

Comment: If I may be a little pedantic, that's not quite what happens. When we use MySQL replication what we get is a stream of events that are pulled from your elected MySQL primary. In the scenario that we have 3 entities: [Web server], [DB Primary] and [DB Replica]. We make actions on the [Web server] that sends some data to the [DB Primary]. With replication set up our [DB replica] is going to connect to the [DB Primary] and consume the events that alter data. This change will effect the local data on the [DB replica]. You describe behaviour like a proxy.

Comment: @BASSJelly - "in the end, using only one db" -- If you mean one physical set of data, but two servers reading/writing it, _No_.  That cannot be done.  Replication (Master-Slave, etc) has _two_ sets of data; two copies of each record inserted into the dataset.  The goal of Replication is for the two copies to 'always' be identical.  You write to the Master; the data is copied to the Slave.

Comment: @BASSJelly - "Data" and "Configuration" are two different things.